# how to display the result in paragraph with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I display the result, now in the code below I only export it to the console but I want it in the browser in a paragraph or other tag. I know this is a stupid question (maybe) but I'm new to `React`.

```js
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      input: 0
    }
  }
 
  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({input: e.target.value})
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let value = eval(this.state.input)
    console.log(value)
   
    
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
          <input type="text " onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/>
          <button>Send</button>
        </form>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you want to show input value in paragraph on change of input right ?

Comment: @GMKHussain i want to show the result of the value in a paragraph, now only is showed in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `value` as a state. Then access it using `this.state.value`

```js
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      input: 0,
      value: "",
    }
  }
 
  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({input: e.target.value})
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let value = eval(this.state.input)
    this.setState({value});
   
    
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
          <input type="text " onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/>
          <button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <p>{this.state.value}</p>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are using the useState hook. how about you set a state which will be updated when you submit your form?

like `const [value, setValue] = useState()` in your function, and then in your submit function call the `setValue(value)`

from there you can access the value state and render it anywhere in your component. Kindly note that you should only use hooks inside a functional component.

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is a working Demo on how you can do what you have in mind:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      input: 0
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      input: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let value = eval(this.state.input)
    console.log(value)


  }

  render() {
    return(
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
            <input type="text " onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/>
            <button>Send</button>
          </form>
          <p>
            {this.state.input}
          </p>
        </div>
      )
  }
}





const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( 
  <React.StrictMode >
    <App / >
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check you can achieve this with some changes.

```js
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      input: 0,
      value: '', //<-- Added
    }
  }
 

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({input: e.target.value})
  }


  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let value = eval(this.state.input)
    console.log(value)
    this.setState({value}); //<--Added 
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
          <input type="text " onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/>
          <button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <p>{this.state.value}</p> <!-- Added -->
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```